# Office Web Apps Word - Configure trusted locations

Tags: excel, excel-services, word, office-web-apps

It is possible to configure the trusted file locations for the Word Web App on SharePoint 2010?
I only can find the settings to configure the supported file formats at the Word-Service Application

For the Excel Web App I can configure the trusted locations.
Central Administration > Excel Services Application > Trusted File Locations
But where is this setting for the Word Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trusted file location for word web app.  If you need to limit its availability you can do so by controlling access to the feature activation's.